# Is it possible to send an ipp print job from the browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, ipp-protocol

Is it possible to send an IPP Print request from the browser using ajax?

I assume it would look something like this:

```
// Data to be sent
var data = "Testing\nTesting\n1\n2\n3";

// Jquery AJAX call
$.ajax("ipp://<printerip>:631", {
    'type': 'POST',
    'data': data,
    'complete': function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        alert('Result:'+textStatus)
    }
});
```

The only problem is I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ipp://<printerip>:631. 
Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Is there anyway to get around this? Or is this simply impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The only thing AJAX and IPP have in common is HTTP
- IPP messages are **byte-encoded** not XML- or JSON-encoded
- You'd need to convert XML/JSON to proper IPP (honestly: doesn't make sense)
- The IPP server should support **CORS** to avoid awkward workarounds

There's a pure JavaScript IPP implementation available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipp (not sure if it runs in browsers)

Answer: It's **not possible** to send an IPP request using **ajax**.

Answer (score 0):

There are chrome extensions which can trigger IPP Print. As chrome doesn't provide any API specific for  this, I assume it is possible to trigger IPP printer by Frontend technology alone.